# How to yield a JSON object from a for loop in scala?

Tags: json, scala, yield

```
  for (character <- content) {
    if (character == '\n') {
      val current_line = line.mkString
      line.clear()
      current_line match {
        case docStartRegex(_*) => {
          startDoc = true
          endText = false
          endDoc = false
        }
        case docnoRegex(group) => {
          docID = group.trim
        }
        case docTextStartRegex(_*) => {
          startText = true
        }
        case docTextEndRegex(_*) => {
          endText = true
          startText = false
        }
        case docEndRegex(_*) => {
          endDoc = true
          startDoc = false
          es_json = Json.obj(
            "_index" -> "ES_SPARK_AP",
            "_type" -> "document",
            "_id" -> docID,
            "_source" -> Json.obj(
              "text" -> textChunk.mkString(" ")
            )
          )
          // yield es_json
          textChunk.clear()
        }
        case _ => {
          if (startDoc && !endDoc && startText) {
            textChunk += current_line.trim
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      line += character
    }
  }
```

The above for-loop parses through a text file and creates a JSON object of each chunk parsed in a loop. This is JSON will be sent to for further processing to Elasticsearch. In python, we can yield the JSON and use generator easily like:

```
def func():
    for i in range(num):
        ... some computations ...
        yield {
            JSON     ## JSON is yielded
        }
for json in func():  ## we parse through the generator here.
    process(json)
```

I cannot understand how I can use `yield` in similar fashion using scala?

Comment: `yield` in scala has absolutely no relation to `yield` in python. `for (x <- y) yield x` is like `[x for x in y]`. Scala's `for` is sugar over chaining map/flatMap calls

Comment: Then how should I solve my problem? I want to keep getting JSON objects from the generator. Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: It almost looks like you're doing text parsing, in which case you may want to look at scala's parser combinators. http://bitwalker.org/blog/2013/08/10/learn-by-example-scala-parser-combinators/

Answer (score 0):

If you want lazy returns, scala does this using Iterator types. Specifically if you want to handle line by line values, I'd split it into lines first with [`.lines`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.StringOps@lines:Iterator[String])

```
val content: String = ???
val results: Iterator[Json] =
  for {
    lines <- content.lines
    line <- lines
  } yield {
    line match {
      case docEndRegex(_*) => ... 
    }
  }
```

You can also use a function directly

```
def toJson(line: String): Json =
  line match {
    case "hi" => Json.obj("line" -> "hi")
    case "bye" => Json.obj("what" -> "a jerk")
  }

val results: Iterator[Json] =
  for {
    lines <- content.lines
    line <- lines
  } yield toJson(line)
```

This is equivalent to doing

```
content.lines.map(line => toJson(line))
```

Or somewhat equivalently in python

```
lines = (line.strip() for line in content.split("\n"))
jsons = (toJson(line) for line in lines)
```

Comment: Can this yield have multiple `cases`?

Comment: `yield` is just going to return the value from the expression on the right. I'll add an example to make it more clear.

Comment: I actually posted the whole loop in the question. See if it clears what I asked? You may ignore some variable there.

Comment: case blocks return the value of the expression that comes after `=>`. I think you should start reading some language-level tutorials because it seems like you're missing basics of the language at this point. I suggest the book Scala for the Impatient

Comment: Yeah, its been a week or so I started with Scala plus I was thinking in lines of Python.